# Create table in Postgressql

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to create a data table in Postgress in Heroku.
While creating a table I'm getting **ERROR:  cannot execute CREATE TABLE in a read-only transaction** error.

Select commands are working fine, but creating table not working.

What permission I'm missing?
I'm trying to do this using Dataclips and https://app.popsql.com/

Comment: The error message says that you are using a read-only transaction (possibly a read-only connection). When you are in a read-only state, you cannot modify the database in any way. This means you cannot do any INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements, or modify the schema (CREATE/ALTER/DROP TABLE, etc).

Comment: That I understand, how to change it? Its hobby dev environment and I can't see option to change it

Comment: I am not sure. It might be that your user/password combination only allows readonly connections, or there might be some settings in the PopSQL connection settings that allow you to switch between read-only and read-write connections. I don't know that program, so I cannot help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Hello salesforce developper,
You seem to have a problem with the credentials of your user. If you read the documentation you will see that the default user credential allow only

````
Run SELECT on tables in the database
INSERT new data
UPDATE data
DELETE data from tables
On Postgres 10 and above, view some usage statistics and monitoring data

So you need to go to the Credentials tab, find the credential you want to configure, and select one of the permission levels. The levels are:

No permissions — no access privileges on any table in the database
Read-only permissions — read access on every table in the database
Read-write permissions — read and write access on every table in the database, including the ability to delete data, plus the ability to generate values from sequences
Configuring permissions on an existing credential```


More information at:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql-credentials#creating-a-new-credential
````